# ROC curve for LinearSVC

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, svm

I'm currently struggling plotting a ROC curve for a `LinearSVC` model. Since `LinearSVC` models can only call `decision_function()` to calculate the y_score (as opposed to the usual `predict_proba()`), I find it diffcult to compute `fpr` and `tpr` for each class. When trying

```
for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
```

I get `IndexError: too many indices for array`. Switching to the solution provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332410/sklearn-roc-for-multiclass-classification) answer would imply binarising the labels, which I would like to avoid. A normal `SVC` model with linear kernel wouldn't allow me to set an l1 penalty for l1-based feature selection, so that's to be avoided as well.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: The definition of ROC curve itself states that it plots the characteristics for a **binary classifier**. If you want to extend this to a multi-class problem the obvious approach is to use a `OneVsRestClassifier` as mentioned in that answer. Is there any specific reason why you don't want to use this approach?

Comment: @panktijk I am not the OP but facing the same problem. The problem is not the multi classes, but rather the fact that the classifier does not return probabilities, but rather only the final classification results. It seems sclearn's functions can't handle those. Is there a nice build in way?

Comment: @panktijk my own question about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59227176/how-to-plot-roc-and-calculate-auc-for-binary-classifier-with-no-probabilities-s?noredirect=1#comment104668366_59227176