# How to get decision function in randomforest in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search

I am using the following code to get the optimised parameters for `randomforest` using `gridsearchcv`.

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42, class_weight = 'balanced')
param_grid = { 
    'n_estimators': [200, 500],
    'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
    'max_depth' : [4,5,6,7,8],
    'criterion' :['gini', 'entropy']
}
k_fold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
CV_rfc = GridSearchCV(estimator=rfc, param_grid=param_grid, cv= 10, scoring = 'roc_auc')
CV_rfc.fit(x_train, y_train)
print(CV_rfc.best_params_)
print(CV_rfc.best_score_)
```

Now, I want to apply the tuned parameters to `X_test`. For that I did the following,

```
pred = CV_rfc.decision_function(x_test)
print(roc_auc_score(y_test, pred))
```

However, `decision_function` does not seem to support `randomforest` as I got the following error.

> AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute
>   'decision_function'.

Is there any other way of doing this?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Aren't you looking for `CV_rfc.predict(x_test)`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your intention is to get a model scoring function so that the scoring can be used for  `auc_roc_score`, then you can go for [`predict_proba()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba)

```
y_pred_proba = CV_rfc.predict_proba(x_test)
print(roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_proba[:,1]))
```

Comment: please let me know if you know an answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55609339/how-to-perform-feature-selection-with-gridsearchcv thank you very much :)

Comment: How can we use this function for GMM clustering.

Comment: roc_auc_score is meant for classification problems. For clustering, you can refer [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering-performance-evaluation)

Comment: I compared the output of `metrics.roc_curve()` using confidence scores from `decision_function()` and probability scores from `predict_proba()`  in a logistic regression classifier, and they both produced the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Your code,

```
pred = CV_rfc.decision_function(x_test)
print(roc_auc_score(y_test, pred))
```

Makes me think that you are trying to make predictions with the trained model.

If you want to get prediction labels you can do like this,

```
pred = CV_rfc.predict(x_test)
```

Then the output will be class labels like `[1, 2, 1, ... ]`

If you want to get class probabilities instead, you can use `predict_proba` like this

```
pred = CV_rfc.predict_proba(x_test)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use either predict() method or to get the optimized random forest model using best_estimator_