# Can you plot a ROC curve with only predicted class labels instead of probabilities?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, roc

I am trying to plot ROC curve in sklearn. The results below are the predicted values (`y_score`) and the labels (`labels`). Is it possible to plot `roc_curve` from that or must one have the raw probabilities?

```
y_score
[1, 0, 0, 1, 10, 5, 12, 14, 6, 9, 10]
labels
[1, 0, 0, 1, 10, 5, 11, 14, 6, 9, 8]
```

I am using [this guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ROC for multiclass classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332410/roc-for-multiclass-classification)

Comment: Ah - I get you now. No, you can't plot a ROC curve from the predicted labels only. A ROC curve is a measure of how the TPR and FPR vary _as you vary the decision threshold for the labels_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't plot a ROC curve from the predicted labels only. A ROC curve is a measure of how the TPR and FPR vary *as you vary the decision threshold for the labels*. If you only have labels, you have a fixed decision threshold already.