# Confusion matrix 5x5 formula for finding accuracy, precision, recall ,and f1-score

Tags: confusion-matrix, precision-recall

im try to study confusion matrix. i know about 2x2 confusion matrix but i still don't understand how to count 5x5 confusion matrix for finding accuracy, precision, recall and, f1 - score. Can anyone help me with this ? i appreciate every help.

Answer (score 2):

See my answer here: [Calculating Equal error rate(EER) for a multi class classification problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72053728/calculating-equal-error-rateeer-for-a-multi-class-classification-problem/73446611#73446611)

In short, one strategy is to split the multiclass problem into a set of binary classification, for each class a "one vs. all others" classification. Then for each binary problem you can calculate F1, precision and recall, and if you want you can average (uniformly or weighted) the scores of each class to get one F1 score which will represent the multiclass problem.

As for confusion matrix larger than 2x2: the rows are the true labels and the columns are predicated labels. Then the number in cell `(i,j)` is the number of samples from class `i` which were classified as class `j` (note that `i=j` corresponds to correct prediction). The accuracy is the trace of the confusion matrix divided by the number of samples.